# how to define variable from mysql output

Tags: php

I have the following variable which returns my URL as needed. But i need to run str_replace() on it to replace a character before echoing it into my HTML code.

```
$url = str_replace("%3A", ":", " . nl2br( $row['url']) . ");
```

As it stands the " . nl2br( $row['url']) . " contains %3A instead of the colon in the URL and for some reason its rendering my links like this

```
http://www.mydomain.com/http%3A//url.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your question is, but it looks like this is what you want:

```
$url = urldecode($row['url']);
```

The %3A is a [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) colon (:).